# Conditional check in a shell

Tags: bash, shell, exit-code

I have a python script `p.py` which does `exit("ABC")` for some files. I would like to write a Ubuntu shell to copy the files which make the script `exit("ABC")` into a folder:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=*.txt
TOOL=p.py
TAREGT=../TARGET/

for f in $FILES
do
    if [ $(python $TOOL $f) = "ABC" ]
    then
        echo "$f"
        cp $f $TARGET
    fi
done
```

but the condition check `if [ $(python $TOOL $f) = "ABC" ]` does not seem to work, it says `./filter.sh: line 13: [: =: unary operator expected`. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: It's a "bash" script, not an "Ubuntu" script. Whether you're running on Ubuntu, AIX or Cygwin doesn't make (much of) a difference. (Likewise, it's a "Python" script, regardless of where you run it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to `exit()` is what the Python script *returns* (success / error). ([Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) of Python's `exit()`. Note how `exit( "ABC" )` doesn't return `"ABC"`, but *prints* that to `stderr` and *returns* `1`.)

The return code is what ends up in the `$?` variable of the calling shell, or what you would test for like this:

```
# Successful if return code zero, failure otherwise.
# (This is somewhat bass-ackwards when compared to C/C++/Java "if".)
if python $TOOL $f
then
    ...
fi
```

The `$(...)` construct is replaced with the *output* of the called script / executable, which is a different thing altogether.

And if you're comparing strings, you have to quote them

```
if [ "$(python $TOOL $f)" = "ABC" ]
```

or use bash's improved test `[[`:

```
if [[ $(python $TOOL $f) = "ABC" ]]
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my `p.py`, there are several kinds of exit: `exit("ABC")`, `exit("DEF")`, etc. how could I check different possibilities in a shell?

Comment: @SoftTimur: It would be a good idea to refer to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) of functions you are using. Any non-zero / non-null parameter to `exit()` indicates **failure** of your script to any callers. I seriously doubt this is what you're looking for, so your script should print its results to output and exit with success (i.e., `exit( 0 )`).

Comment: @SoftTimur In particular, your exit code should be an integer value between 0 and 255 (or -128 to 127, depending on whether you treat it as signed or unsigned - but it should be a single-byte value)...

Comment: @twalberg: Not necessarily; Python adds extra functionality to `exit()` that makes SoftTimur's code perfectly valid: The text gets printed to `stderr`, and the script terminates with a return code of 1.

Comment: @DevSolar Python may allow that, but as far as a shell script wrapper is concerned, the exit code of any process (whether it's Python, Perl, Ada or Cobol) is a single-byte integer.